# G-WAN All CSP's Respond with Content Type of text/plain

Tags: python, http-headers, g-wan

[[ **[Solved] The latest update of G-WAN has fixed this default MIME type.** ]]

---

G-WAN 4.3.11 is returning all of my csp files as type "text/plain". How can this be fixed?! At the moment it is hardly anything more than a static file server.

E.g., //127.0.0.1:8080/?hello.py responds with "Hello, Python!<br>" (as text/plain)

This should return "Hello, Python!" without displaying the <br> (as text/html)

Notes:

Previous versions of GWAN are working fine. Running Fedora 18

The csp source is compiling and returning the correct output, it's just a matter of the server not responding with the correct content type.

.html files return text/html, as they should.

Python: print(os.environ.get('CONTENT_TYPE')) returns "None"

Python: os.environ['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'text/html' has no impact

```
Request URL://localhost:8080/?hello.py
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
GET /?hello.py HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Query String Parameters
hello.py:

Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: G-WAN
Date: Tue, 12 Mar 2013 18:50:33 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Mar 2013 18:50:33 GMT
ETag: "c9ddeef-513f78fa-25"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 37
```

Comment: There's a v4.3.11 change that has made **text/plain** the default MIME type - but that's an **unwanted side-effect** and this will be corrected tomorrow. I did not understood what you meant initially, but that's much clearer now you have edited the question.

Comment: G-WAN **v4.3.14** has been published, and it restored the default MIME type to **"text/html"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> G-WAN 4.3.11 is returning all of my csp files as type "text/plain". 
>   How can I fix this?

There is no way for G-WAN to *guess* what MIME type a script wants to use.
Application servers don't do that because MIME type detection would be too slow and could be wrong.

G-WAN C/C++/D/CS/Java scripts let you specify the reply MIME type directly with `get_env()`, or they let you to use `build_headers()`, or thy let you write the HTTP headers directly in the reply buffer.

But with CGI languages like Perl or Python, if you want to change the value of a specific HTTP header like "Content-type", then you have to write your own HTTP headers, and specify what you consider as the relevant "Content-Type".

G-WAN exports SERVER environment variables to let CGI scripts know about the HTTP request headers without having to parse them (these variables are not used to modify G-WAN's automatically generated HTTP headers).

For how to fetch SERVER environment variables from a G-WAN Python script, look at the [hello.py](http://gwan.ch/source/hello.py) example.

---

UPDATE

Now your question has been rewritten, it is clear that your issue was about the *default* MIME type of G-WAN scripts. We shipped v4.3.14 to fix this v4.3.11 issue.

Regarding the supported MIME types, they are documented in the G-WAN PDF manual, and, as indicated there, we routinely add entries suggested by users when it can be of general use.

Note that, for the case you were discussing to (G-WAN scripts), a MIME type configuration file would be poinless because G-WAN scripts *either* pick the default MIME type or they explicitely overwride it in the "Content-Type" HTTP header.

G-WAN avoids configuration files by either dynamically tuning options (like adaptative timeouts, which are much more efficient than any fixed value), or by using the file system instead of relying on a configuration file which merely describbes what the file system defines anyway.

G-WAN is a tool made by and for programmers, and not all programmers have the time to learn the tousands of proprietary file configuration options of each server they have to use. Please don't shoot us for trying to keep things simple with G-WAN - a rare exception.

Comment: Got it, thanks. When did this change? I used G-WAN with PHP (when you first started supporting it) and never had to set the content-type, but now it loads as text/plain.

Comment: It just breaks most of the samples, e.g., //localhost:8080/?charts.c, //localhost:8080/?json.c, etc.

Comment: Only serving static content (text/plain, images, html, css), how is dynamic content generated on the server side -- it just spits out the HTML as plain text? Are custom HTTP headers now a requirement for all server-side languages that wish to spit out a webpage (HTML), including all of the samples, which no longer ship in a working state?! Say Whaaat?!

Comment: Considering I've been encouraging others to use G-WAN, this concerns me that custom headers are required for all server-side languages that spit out HTML.

Comment: "No application server on Earth does that because MIME type detection would be too slow and could be wrong." Defaulting to text/plain on a web application server is wrong more often than it's right, wouldn't you say?

Comment: There's a v4.3.11 change that has made **text/plain** the default MIME type - but that's an **unwanted side-effect** and this will be corrected tomorrow. I did not understood what you meant initially, but that's much clearer now you have edited the question.

Comment: G-WAN v4.3.14 has been published, and it restored the default MIME type to "text/html".

Comment: Gil, you're awesome, thanks for listening to your users (on legit complaints/feedback, not just the one's trying to stir up shit.) I'll update G-WAN to the latest version. That change crippled my entire application (and possible other's too), so thanks again for the update.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the latest release of G-WAN.